# Битрикс включить вывод свойства элемента инфоблока в умном фильтре раздела инфоблока через api

Tags: php, битрикс

Реализую импорт каталога через api Битрикс. Программно создаю

- разделы инфоблока
- элементы инфоблока
- свойства элемента инфоблока
- значения свойств элемента инфоблока.

Нужно импортировать данные так, чтобы при заходе в раздел каталога в умном фильтре выводились только те свойства, которые есть у товаров данного раздела.

Подчеркиваю, что вывод всех существующих свойств элементов инфоблока в умном фильтре недопустим, только те, что актуальны для данного раздела.

По мере импорта мне нужно задавать соответствие между свойством элемента инфоблока и разделом инфоблока, при заходе в который свойство должно попасть в умный фильтр.

Исходные данные:

> `$iblock_id` - id инфоблока
>   `$section_id` - id раздела
>   `$prop_id` - id свойства элемента инфоблока

После создания свойства вызываю метод:

```
<?
CIBlockSectionPropertyLink::Add(
    $section_id,
    $prop_id,
    $arLink = array(
        'IBLOCK_ID' => $iblock_id,
        'SMART_FILTER' => 'Y',
        'DISPLAY_TYPE' => 'L',
    )
);
```

В итоге таблицу `b_iblock_section_property`, в которой хранится соответствие `раздел`-`id_свойства`-`параметры вывода в фильтре` данные попадают:

```
IBLOCK_ID  | SECTION_ID  | PROPERTY_ID | SMART_FILTER   | DISPLAY_TYPE
------------------------------------------------------------------
$iblock_id | $section_id | $prop_id    | Y              | L
```

После привязки свойства к элементу, ожидаю увидеть свойство в умном фильтре раздела, но его там нет.

Подскажите, в чем ошибка?

Comment: `if(CIBlock::GetArrayByID($IBLOCK_ID, "SECTION_PROPERTY") !== "Y") {
           $ib = new CIBlock;
           $ib->Update($IBLOCK_ID, array("SECTION_PROPERTY" => "Y"));
       }`
должен быть в да выставлен

Comment: @Oleksandr, никаких изменений

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в подключении компонента "Умный фильтр". В параметры передавался некорректный параметр "id раздела":

```
<?
// Умный фильтр
$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:catalog.smart.filter",
    ".default",
    array(
        "SECTION_ID" => $section_id,  // ID раздела инфоблока
        // прочие параметры
    )
);
?>
```